# <p:ajax> update not working primefaces 4.0 to 6.2 Migration

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Primefaces 4.0 to 6.2 migration that time Ajax update event not working

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="ddl_district"
 value="#{village_Entry.ddl_district}"
 valueChangeListener="#{village_Entry.ddl_district_changed}"
 styleClass="component-width">

     <f:selectItems value="#{village_Entry.ddl_district_options}"/>                                                                  

    <p:ajax event="change"
     Process="ddl_district"
     Update="ddl_taluka"/>

 </p:selectOneMenu>

 public void ddl_district_changed(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    ddl_district = event.getNewValue().toString();
    setDdl_taluka();      
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at the [ask] page and improve your question: why does this not work/what have you tried to solve it/do you get any error message? Thank you!

Comment: No, since you can do a lot of debugging... Is a request send to the server at all (compare 4.0 and 6.2) is there an error in the http response or not... Is it processed, but just no update so @AlexanderLeithner is correct that you need to and can be more precise. And please try to make a real [mcve] as requested in [ask]. I did not downvote but please also read http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 0):

you should make update more accurate:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="ddl_district">                                                                    

<p:ajax event="change"
 Process="ddl_district"
 Update=":FORM_NAME:ddl_taluka"/>
```

Comment: Not working and before did migration its work good so i think if we do not mention form name then also it's work.

Comment: @KunalShah: unless you relied on what turned out to be a bug. So please [mcve] (and tried update and process instead of Update and Process?)